# RTL Refrences in XePersian package

Tags: right-to-left, xepersian

In my Persian paper all references are in Latin script.

How I can insert references (Bibliography) RTL in XePersian,
and how I can convert digits in URLs to west Arabic.

MWE:

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎‎
\usepackage[]{hyperref}‎‎
‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎‎
‎\settextfont{Yas‎‎}‎‎
‎\setdigitfont{Yas}‎‎
‎\begin{document}‎‎

%‎ ‎1st‎ ‎issue‎
‎\url{‎‎http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/06/15/‎wikipedia_can_damage_your_grades}‎‎

% 2nd‎ ‎issue‎‎
برای‎ ‎nها‎‎‎ ....

ابتدا‎ n‎ام

‎\end{document}‎‎
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a version that you can try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\setLTRbibitems
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\resetlatinfont
\bibitem{reference1} 1st‎ ‎issue‎ ‎\url{‎‎http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/06/15/‎wikipedia_can_damage_your_grades}‎‎
\bibitem{reference2} 2nd‎ ‎issue \rl{برای‎ ‎\lr{CRM}ها‎‎‎ \ldots ‎ ابتدا‎ \lr{CRM}ام}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\begin{LTRbibitems}
\resetlatinfont
\bibitem{reference1} 1st‎ ‎issue‎ ‎\url{‎‎http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/06/15/‎wikipedia_can_damage_your_grades}‎‎
\end{LTRbibitems}
\bibitem{reference2} 
برای \lr{CRM}ها \ldots\ ابتدا \lr{CRM}ام
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

whichever you prefer.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. What about 2nd issue? (nام  Graphها) do not displayied properly.

Comment: Well, you are using Latin script and Latin font and evidently that can not typeset Persian so you need `\rl` there. See updated answer.

Comment: I actually want to type CRMها that is not a formula (I do not want wrap it with $) and your solution will not work without $
Also notice that 1st and 2nd issues are not in bibliography. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer for the third time.

Comment: I got all, thanks. just notice that 1st and 2nd issues are not in bibliography. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to include another alternative. You can erase 1st & 2nd issue from my answer. Easy!

Comment: the solution break when using Bibtex , "مراجع" title is not displayed. 
‎\setLTRbibitems‎‎
‎\bibliographystyle{plain}‎‎
‎\resetlatinfont‎
‎\bibliography{report‎}‎‎

Comment: You need to use `persian-bib` package for that which inserts these commands automatically: http://ctan.org/pkg/persian-modern

Comment: I gave an incorrect link. The correct link is http://ctan.org/pkg/persian-bib